Origin checking failed - http://localhost:8000/ does not match any trusted origins
I have been struggling with a CORS issue with login form POST request coming from React dev server to my django backend where I am using Django's LOginView module for login requests API.
These are my settings for settings.py
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    "DELETE",
    "GET",
    "OPTIONS",
    "PATCH",
    "POST",
    "PUT",
)
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    "accept",
    "authorization",
    "content-type",
    "user-agent",
    "x-csrftoken",
    "x-requested-with",
)
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS =  [
     'http://localhost:3000',  
]


CORS_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
     'http://localhost:3000',  
]
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
     'http://localhost:3000', 
]
CORS_ORIGINS_WHITELIST = [
     'http://localhost:3000',  
]

and for react I am implementing a proxy in package.json
"proxy": "http://localhost:8000/",

my api for user token retrieval works fine but I believe something is wrong with the CSRF verification.
I have already tried the settings referred in documentation:
https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/
and someone facing the similar problem in the forum
https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/origin-checking-failed-with-ssl-https/20158/13

For not facing CORS error in DRF& React, I recomment use nginx reverse proxy.

Where does the message in the title come from? If you run into a error message, it should be in the body of your question.

@jub0bs It appears on django's terminal whenever I try to fetch a POST login form request from react.
const data = {
username: username,
password: password
};
  const response = await fetch('/login/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRFToken': token_csrf
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      'username': username,
      'password': password
    })
  });


the error you are getting is for the http://localhost:8000/ but you are adding http://localhost:3000 to settings just change the port to 8000 and it should be fine
